# What version of Ubuntu is best for LAMP and web development server? Why ubuntu 32 bit is recommended?

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu

I'm just thinking about installing Ubuntu as my web development server featuring mostly LAMP environment, also RoR and Python, but all for web development. I'm thinking about running some version control server there as well, but that's all.

So I navigated to [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and got confused, as recommended version is 32 bit. My PC is running Intel i7 and  was thinking that 64 bit will be better and faster for me.

Why 32 bit is recommended?
Are there any reasonable explanations?
What version is best for things I will work on?

BTW I'm not going to write code on this platform - this msut be only web development and version control server.

Comment: probably best in superuser...

Comment: To be honest, I really don't understand those minuses... if for you answer is so obvious why don't you post it? Or if question is not good enough, why don't you tell me, what's wrong about it? I'm not expert in linux and server things, so I'm asking... If you are expert, you should answer...

Comment: @Carlos: any question that asks about the "best" anything is not a constructive question. Any question that's not asking about programming is off-topic on stackoverflow. Read the FAQ instead of whining about downvotes.

Comment: Im whining because nobody's explaining downvote... so you're the first, and I really appreciate this! Many questions on stackoverflow are about best things, and are not downvoted. And yeah - maybe it's not programming question, but for me as a programmer it's important what to choose, as a platform for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended version is 32 bits because it works in both 32 and 64 bits (x86-compatible) platforms, and as there are many people that really don't know what their cpu is, what the heck is an *i5* or *celeron* or *ahtlon 3200+*, it's easier for them to tell everyone (who doesn't know better) to download the 32 bits version.

Answer (score 1):

64Bit is not necessarily faster, usually with some very intensive tasks you can notice the real difference. I guess the reason that they recommend the 32bit version is because 32Bit processes use less RAM, which can sometimes be a problem on a server.

I'd always go for 64Bit, but if you are short on memory giving 32Bit a try wouldn't be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Go for 64-bit, then you don't get the memory limit, 32-bit system suffers from. And as far as I can see you aren't going to run any programs which don't support 64-bit